# Bootstrap navbar appearing vertically instead of horizontal

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a project and my navbar is appearing as a vertical list instead of horizontally across the page. I've tried several different ways to fix and looked at other posts. I believe all my code is up to date with the newest version of bootstrap which seemed to be an issue with others, so I am stumped. Here is my application.html.erb file, with the code for the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BandArt</a>
  </div>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon"></span>My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first, you have one too many `</div>`s

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. The only issue that I see is you have one too many divs. Here is the code that I used:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br><br>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BandArt</a>
  </div>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon"></span>My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this both in rails, and in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/523cv6uL/) both worked, there should not be a difference.

hope this helps!

Comment: I've forked your fiddle, @ https://jsfiddle.net/4xoj74fL/ and changed the link part alone to latest v4alpha Bootstrap links, and the OP's issue exists.

Answer (score 1):

you have not closed `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top>`

please close that `navbar` `class` that you have created in the first line.. then check, it will display horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You have one extra `</div>` tag closed and `<nav>` tag not closed